# Assign <div> numbered id through loop in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So what I did was set the id of a div as i and set i = 0. I want to set up a loop to assign the id of the div based on what the object's place in an array is. How would I do this? At first I thought I could set a for loop in the return section of the App component but that didn't work. I'd really appreciate any help I'm kinda lost.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import asteroid from './images/asteroid.png';
import './App.css';

const i = 0;
function HoverObject(props) {
  const [hovering, setHovering] = React.useState(false);

  const { item } = props;
  return (
    <div className="Object" id={i}>
      <strong>{item.fullname}</strong>
      <div className="image">
        <img class='rotate'
          src={asteroid}
          height='100' 
          width='100'
          alt={"picture of asteroid"}
          onMouseOver={() => setHovering(true)}
          onMouseOut={() => setHovering(false)}
        />
      </div>
      {hovering && <div className="info">
      <ul>
        <li>Average Lunar Distance: {item.average_lunar_distance} or {item.average_lunar_distance*384317+" km"}</li>
        <li>Sentry ID: {item.sentryId}</li>
        <li>Predicted to be nearest: {item.year_range_min + " - " + item.year_range_max}</li>
        <li>{item.potential_impacts} Possible Potential Impacts </li>
        <li>Impact Probability: {item.impact_probability}</li>
        <li>Absolute Magnitude: {item.absolute_magnitude}</li>
        <li>Estimated Diameter: {item.estimated_diameter}</li>
        <li>Last Observed: {item.last_obs}</li>
        <li><a href={item.url_nasa_details}> NASA Center fo Near Earth Object Studies Link to Object </a></li>
      </ul>
        </div>}
    </div>
  );

}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    objects: []
  };
  async componentDidMount(){
    const url = "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/sentry?is_active=true&page=0&size=30&api_key=XXX"
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const sentry_objects = data.sentry_objects;
    this.setState({
      objects: sentry_objects
    })
    console.log(this.state.objects);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        {this.state.objects.map(obj => (
          <HoverObject key={obj} item={obj} />
          for (i; i < objects.length; i+=1);
        ))}
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `id` as a prop to `HoverObject` and set the id attribute of the div.

```
function HoverObject(props) {
  const [hovering, setHovering] = React.useState(false);

  const { item, id } = props;
  return (
    <div className="Object" id={id}>
...
```

And pass the index parameter of the `array::map` function (+1 if it matters) to the component as a prop

```
<div className="App" >
  {this.state.objects.map((obj, index) => (
    <HoverObject key={obj} item={obj} id={index + 1} />
  ))}
</div>
```